# how do you reference divs in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class = "badge">
   <div class = "badge-header">
   </div>
</div>
```

What's the proper way to style badge-header in css?

Is it

```
.badge .badge-header {
}

or 
.badge-header {
}
```

also how do we structure our css names? How do we structure our divs and what selectors should we use for each above?

If you have a div inside a div, what is the naming convention that we should stick to in CSS?

Comment: `.badge .badge-header`  would select every `.badge-header` under `.badge ` and `.badge-header` would select all `.badge-header` in page

Answer (score 6):

Both

but the first will apply the style only when the "badge-header" is inside of a "badge"

in the second will apply for all "badge-header" elements.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/6bvLtqLw/

CSS

```
.badge-header{
    color:blue;
}

.badge .badge-header{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="badge">
<div class="badge-header">
        inside
    </div>
</div>
<div class="badge-header">
    outside
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both work

```
.badge .badge-header {
}
```

above one applies style to those elements with class '.badge-header' AND are under elements with class '.badge'

```
.badge-header {
}
```

and the above one applies style to all the elements with class '.badge-header' regardless of element's position in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Both

but the first will apply the style only when the "badge-header" is inside of a "badge"

```
.badge .badge-header {
    }
```

in the second will apply for all "badge-header" elements.

```
.badge-header {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first variant obviously will only style `.badge-header` if used in the context of a `.badge`. The second will apply to all `.badge-header`regardless of their context.

If you are certain `.badge-header` will never need to be used *outside* of `.badge`, you go with variant two as it is shorter and more concise.

If it might be useful to reuse the `.badge-header` in different context than only `.badge`, then use ***both** variants. Put all styles that **all** `.badge-header` have in common in `.badge-header { ... }`. Put the context-dependent styles in `.badge .badge-header { ... }`.